# How to separate column values into diffenerent column using hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

For input:

```
 name year run
 1. a    2008 4
 2. a    2009 3
 3. a    2008 4
 4. b    2009 8
 5. b    2008 5
```

Output in hive:

```
 name 2008 2009
 1. a 8 3
 2. b 5 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed years:

```
select name,
       max(case when year=2008 then run end) as year_2008, 
       max(case when year=2009 then run end) as year_2009, 
       ... and so on
  from my_table
  group by name;
```

It is not possible in Hive to generate such columns dynamically, but you can select distinct years first and generate this SQL using shell.

Comment: How to find a Year wise runs of top 5 batsman, using these syntax?

Comment: calculate dense_rank() over (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY run DESC) as rank in a subquery (instead of from my_table) and filter by where rank<=5

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you need some of runs per year pivoted into year columns

You need sum function, not max

```
select
sum(case when year=2008 then run else 0 end) 2008_run,
sum(case when year=2009 then run else 0 end) 2009_run,
from table t1
group by name;
```

To find out top 5 run scorer in each year.

```
with table1 as
(
select name, sum(runs) as RunsPerYear, year from myTable group by name, year
)
table2 as
(
select name, year, RunsPerYear, dense_rank() over (partition by name, year order by RunsPerYear) as rnk from table2
)
select name, year, RunsPerYear from table2 where rnk<=5;
```